# Getting description using selenium xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, automated-tests

I am trying to get the job description for job search page indeed.com This is how it looks like

[image]
Provide technical leadership around 
**QA**
 automation to IT teams. Work with various team to promote 
**QA**
 processes, practices and standardization....

Any idea how can I get that description? I tried the following:
//span[contains(@class,'summary')]

That does not give me the text description. Should I xpath or is there any other solution? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I will be using java, thanks

Comment: Your xpath looks Ok, what do you mean That does not give me the text description?? What are you getting then??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath are correct.

```
//span[contains(@class,'summary')]
//span[@class='summary']
```

I'm a Python guy, But I translated it to Java. You can do:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.name("summary"));
element = driver.findElement(By.className("summary"));
element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('span[class="summary"]');
```

And remember that If you want the element text, every element has the method `.getText()`, the `find*` functions only retrieve the element/s.

Double check you were not using `driver.findElements(By.xpath())` in plural. In that case you should first retrieve the individual elements. Then access to the `.getText()` method.

```
description = driver.findElement(By.className("summary")).getText();
System.out.print(description);
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
description = driver.findElement(By.className("summary"));
description_text = description.getAttribute("innerHTML");
System.out.print(description_text);
```

If your problem is that your element is not visible or reachable (stale). Then you can use javascript.

```
element = driver.executeScript("return document.querySelector('span[class=\"summary\"]');");
```

For more reference:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html

Comment: I fixed some errors that I made when translating from python to java ;) If works, mark it as accepted ! If not give us more feedback, maybe exceptions or tthe related code.